# How to create a calendar table in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

with the earliest date being 2021 Aug 1st 12 AM with increments of 30 minutes and the maximum date being DateTime.LocalNow()?

Expected Output

```
08/01/2021 12:00:00 AM 
08/01/2021 12:30:00 AM 
08/01/2021 01:00:00 AM
```

Code

```
    Source = List.DateTimes(#datetime(2021, 08, 01, 00, 00, 0), Duration.Days(Duration.From(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-(#datetime(2021, 08, 01, 00, 00, 0)))), #duration(0, 0, 30, 0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
```

But i don't think this is the right way to go. Besides i get this error anyway

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Date and DateTime.
Details:
    Operator=-
    Left=10/20/2021
    Right=8/1/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: This is error srouce: `DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())-(#datetime(2021, 08, 01, 00, 00, 0))`. Don't convert `DateTime.LocalNow()` now to a date type if you want to subtract a datetime type. Simplify to `DateTime.LocalNow()-#datetime(2021, 08, 01, 00, 00, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis Olson. Makes the code work but what i want is from August 1st till now, i want each date laid out like          08/01/2021 12:00:00 AM -  08/01/2021 12:30:00 AM -08/01/2021 01:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following M code in power query.
This will give 100 dates. You can chnage the step size 100 to your required value.

```
    let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtQ1sNQ1MlAwNLIyMAAipdhYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Datetime = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Datetime", type datetime}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each DateTime.LocalNow()),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type datetime}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Datetime", "Starttime"}, {"Custom", "Endtime"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Dates", each List.DateTimes([Starttime], 100, #duration(0, 0, 30, 0))),
    #"Expanded Dates1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Dates")
in
    #"Expanded Dates1"
```

Comment: This is not giving me datetime though - just the date

Comment: I have edited answer